# Converting from PROP_ENTRY to PROP_ENTRY_TYPE

Tags: c++, activex, atl

I've inherited an old project that was using Ole and ActiveX tools. Compiling gives a deprecation warning on the PROP_ENTRY macro, and they replacing with PROP_ENTRY_TYPE, but that takes a 4th parameter. I found a list of types, like VT_BSTR, VT_UNIT, VT_UNKNOWN, etc. but it's unclear to me how to figure out what the types should be. Since the old macro did not require the type, was there a default type in the old way of doing things that I could use? Failing that, anyone have suggestions as to what the types should be for any of these items? I tried using VT_BSTR for everything, as most of the values could be (?) strings, but that gets a failure way down in some ActiveX stuff; also tried VT_UNKNOWN. Suggestions appreciated. Things do run (with some problems) with the old code, but would be nice to be able to move our code base forward.
Thanks,
Ken

```
BEGIN_PROPERTY_MAP(CCiButton)
#if 1
        // old style
    PROP_ENTRY("Caption", DISPID_CAPTION, CLSID_NULL)
    PROP_ENTRY("Back Color", DISPID_BACKCOLOR, CLSID_StockColorPage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Fill Color", DISPID_FILLCOLOR, CLSID_StockColorPage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Font", DISPID_FONT, CLSID_StockFontPage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Picture", DISPID_PICTURE, CLSID_StockPicturePage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Button Style", 1, CLSID_CiButtonProp)
    PROP_ENTRY("Text Color", 2, CLSID_StockColorPage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Text Shadow Color", 3, CLSID_StockColorPage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Tool Tip Text", 4, CLSID_CiButtonProp)
    PROP_ENTRY("Disabled Picture", 5, CLSID_StockPicturePage)
    PROP_ENTRY("Enabled", DISPID_ENABLED, CLSID_NULL)
#else
        // new style, fails.
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Caption", DISPID_CAPTION, CLSID_NULL, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Back Color", DISPID_BACKCOLOR, CLSID_StockColorPage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Fill Color", DISPID_FILLCOLOR, CLSID_StockColorPage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Font", DISPID_FONT, CLSID_StockFontPage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Picture", DISPID_PICTURE, CLSID_StockPicturePage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Button Style", 1, CLSID_CiButtonProp, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Text Color", 2, CLSID_StockColorPage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Text Shadow Color", 3, CLSID_StockColorPage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Tool Tip Text", 4, CLSID_CiButtonProp, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Disabled Picture", 5, CLSID_StockPicturePage, VT_UNKNOWN)
    PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Enabled", DISPID_ENABLED, CLSID_NULL, VT_UNKNOWN)
#endif
END_PROPERTY_MAP()
```

Answer (score 1):

The varient type that needs to be put as the third parameter is the type of value returned by the property that you are using

for example PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Enabled", DISPID_ENABLED, CLSID_NULL, VT_BOOL)

Now, if you are not sure what is the data type that should be send, then you can pass VT_EMPTY. reason for this is that both the macros PROP_ENTRY and PROP_ENTRY_TYPE internally call same API which takes the varient type as one of the parameter.

In case of PROP_ENTRY_TYPE the varient type that is passed is the one passed in the macro.

In case of PROP_ENTRY the varient type that is passed is VT_EMPTY.
So, you can pass VT_EMPTY directly in PROP_ENTRY_TYPE to avoid the issue.

for example PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Enabled", DISPID_ENABLED, CLSID_NULL, VT_EMPTY)

Regards,
Rishabh

Answer (score 0):

`VT_UNKNOWN` means a variant type that holds `IUnknown*` interface pointer, which is not your scenario (font and picture properties might have interface pointers there but not the other).

You will find type to `VT_` constant mapping in Windows SDK files, e.g. OAIdl.h:

```
/* VARIANT STRUCTURE
 *
 *  VARTYPE vt;
 *  WORD wReserved1;
 *  WORD wReserved2;
 *  WORD wReserved3;
 *  union {
 *    LONGLONG       VT_I8
 *    LONG           VT_I4
 *    BYTE           VT_UI1
 *    SHORT          VT_I2
 *    FLOAT          VT_R4
 *    DOUBLE         VT_R8
 *    VARIANT_BOOL   VT_BOOL
 *    SCODE          VT_ERROR
 *    CY             VT_CY
 *    DATE           VT_DATE
 *    BSTR           VT_BSTR
 *    IUnknown *     VT_UNKNOWN
 *    IDispatch *    VT_DISPATCH
 *    SAFEARRAY *    VT_ARRAY
```

This is where you will pick the ones you need from.